# Generate #include macro from environment variable

Tags: c, include, environment-variables, c-preprocessor

as you say, it works.

But can I build -in some way- the string for the include directive ?
Something like

in .login

```
setenv REPO "/tmp"
```

compile

```
# gcc -D"REPO=${REPO}" source.c
```

in source.c

```
#ifdef REPO
    #include ${REPO}/my_dir/my_file.h 
#endif
```

thanks

Comment: The preprocessor is a compile-time only thing, it can't do anything at runtime. It's also a separate language from C, and so have no knowledge of C variables.

Comment: However, you fix it by defining macros on the command line, like e.g. `gcc DMY_INCLUDE="$MY_ENV_VAR" my_source.c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Joachim writes, in GCC you can use the [`-D` flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_2.html#SEC11) to `#define` things from the command-line:

```
gcc -DTEST source.c

// in source.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  #ifdef TEST
  printf("TEST macro is #defined!\n"); // only runs if -DTEST
  #endif
  return 0;
}
```

You can easily plug in environment variables (at compile-time) via this
mechanism:

```
gcc "-DTEST=$MY_ENV_VAR" source.c
```

If you need to use the run-time value of the environment variable, then the macro preprocessor (`#define`, `#ifdef`, ...) can't help you. Use `getenv()` instead, and forget about macros.

More to the point:

```
#include TEST
int main() {
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Will work fine *only* if compiled with `"-DTEST=<stdio.h>"` (note the quotes).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ! I will  try yours suggestion